# EF Core Query Custom IdentiyUser

Tags: c#, ef-core-2.1

I am still relatively new to EF Core and beforehand I used PetaPoco, so please forgive my ignorance. In my database, I added the following fields to my AspNetUsers table:

- Elevated
- Deactivated
- FirstName
- LastName

I then created the following classes following [this blog article](https://adrientorris.github.io/aspnet-core/identity/extend-user-model.html):

```
public partial class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public bool? Deactivated { get; set; }
    public bool? Elevated { get; set; }
    [StringLength(255)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [StringLength(255)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class ApplicationClaimsPrincipalFactory : UserClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>
{
    public ApplicationClaimsPrincipalFactory(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager, IOptions<IdentityOptions> optionsAccessor) : base(userManager, roleManager, optionsAccessor)
    { }

    public override async Task<ClaimsPrincipal> CreateAsync(ApplicationUser user)
    {
        var principal = await base.CreateAsync(user);

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(user.FirstName))
        {
            ((ClaimsIdentity)principal.Identity).AddClaims(new[] {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.GivenName, user.FirstName)
            });
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(user.LastName))
        {
            ((ClaimsIdentity)principal.Identity).AddClaims(new[] {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Surname, user.LastName)
            });
        }

        return principal;
    }
}
```

I also setup the `AddIdentity` and `AddScoped` methods too in my Startup.cs file.

What I do not understand going forward from this point is how to query the table, returning my custom properties. In my controller, I want to do something like this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets every User.
/// </summary>
/// <returns>HTTP Result</returns>
[HttpGet]
[Route("")]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<ApplicationUser>>> GetUsers()
{
    var users = await this._context.Users.Select(user => new
    {
        user.Id,
        user.Decativated,
        user.Elevated,
        user.Email,
        user.FirstName,
        user.LastName
    }).ToListAsync();

    return Ok(users);
}
```

But obviously I can't because the properties don't exist on the Users DbSet.

So long story short, I think that I have everything setup properly but how do I actually query my extended IdentityUser?

**EDIT**

As requested, the following is my DbContext. I only have a dummy table wired up right now as I was just trying to get the extensions on the AspNetUsers table working first:

```
public partial class [removed for confidentiality]Context : IdentityDbContext
{
    public [removed for confidentiality]Context()
    {
    }

    public [removed for confidentiality]Context(DbContextOptions<[removed for confidentiality]Context> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Foo> Foos { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
        {
        }
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.HasAnnotation("ProductVersion", "[removed for confidentiality]");

        modelBuilder.Entity<Foo>(entity =>
        {
            entity.Property(e => e.FooName).IsUnicode(false);
        });

        OnModelCreatingPartial(modelBuilder);
    }

    partial void OnModelCreatingPartial(ModelBuilder modelBuilder);
}
```

Comment: Can you post also your DbContext implementation details?

Comment: @dropoutcoder Yep, I'll put it up. But right now I just have a dummy table wired up (just to have something there).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify type parameter(s) for `IdentityDbContext`. You need to inherit from [`IdentityDbContext<TUser>` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.entityframeworkcore.identitydbcontext-1?view=aspnetcore-2.1). Without type parameters you are using classes defined in ASP.NET Core Identity. Everything you'd like to change must be reflected in your code.

```
public partial class [removed for confidentiality]Context : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public [removed for confidentiality]Context()
    {
    }

    public [removed for confidentiality]Context(DbContextOptions<[removed for confidentiality]Context> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Foo> Foos { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
        {
        }
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.HasAnnotation("ProductVersion", "[removed for confidentiality]");

        modelBuilder.Entity<Foo>(entity =>
        {
            entity.Property(e => e.FooName).IsUnicode(false);
        });

        OnModelCreatingPartial(modelBuilder);
    }

    partial void OnModelCreatingPartial(ModelBuilder modelBuilder);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm glad it was such a simple fix.

Comment: I am happy to help!